# Ruby - array inside quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby / Ruby On Rails, I have a string containing an array literal:

```
"[523, 456]"
```

How do I convert this string to array

```
[523, 456]
```

Comment: Where does that string come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

```
JSON.parse("[523, 456]")
=> [523, 456]
```

if you're in plain ruby don't forget to

```
require 'json'
```

Comment: You could be jumping to conclusions here. Without knowing where it came from you can't just assume the input is valid JSON - and usually whenever you're manually parsing JSON it's usually because you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Yes, the op is just few words, there is no so much to think about it...

Comment: Yeah, its a very low effort question and most likely a XY problem as are 80% of SO questions from new users.

Comment: `arr = eval "[523, 456]"` is another option, though it comes with potentially greater security risk.

Comment: @max I agree, the input JSON is an output from SELECT group_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(device_id) FROM devices_groups WHERE group_id IN (69) AND device_id IN (525101,525102) GROUP BY group_id
=> {69=>"[525101, 525102]"}. I want to use the output[69] as an array.

Comment: In that case you actually need to use JSON parse. ActiveRecord won't automatically parse  JSON unless its a JSON column defined in the database schema. If thats a problem you can create a materialized view containing and define it as a JSON column or  array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure Ruby approach that should work for your particular use case, assuming all array elements are integers:

```
"[523, 456]"[1..-2].split(", ").map(&:to_i)
```